# Multiplicar preço de produtos pela quantidade

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Bom dia. Sou um programador iniciante e estou desenvolvendo um app de vendas, onde o sistema inclui os produtos dinamicamente na venda. Os produtos já estão cadastrados no banco de dados, e queria que ao digitar a quantidade de produtos que serão vendidos, ele já multiplique pelo preço.

Código:

```js
function somaTotal() {
    var total = 0;

    $(".input_preco_venda").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

    $(".soma_venda").text(total);

    $("[name=soma_venda]").val(total);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("keyup", ".input_quantidade_venda", function() {
        var indice = $(".input_quantidade_venda").index(this);
        var n1 = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        
        // Esse "10" é o que deveria ser o preço do produto
        $('.input_preco_venda:eq('+indice+')').html(n1 * 10);
        somaTotal();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input placeholder="Digite o Produto" name="input_produto_venda[]" id="produto_venda" type="text" class="validate autocomplete_produto_venda">
        <div id="caixa_auto_complete_produto_venda"></div>
        <label class="active" for="input_produto_venda[]">Produto</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s2">
        <input placeholder=" " name="input_quantidade_venda[]" class="input_quantidade_venda" type="text" class="validate" value="1">
        <label class="active" for="input_quantidade_venda[]">Quantidade</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s2">
        <div class="input_preco_venda"></div>
          <label class="active" for="input_preco_venda">Preço</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Vc quer que puxe do banco o valor em tempo real?

Comment: Exatamente @Sam

Comment: Aí vc tem que usar Ajax. Tem mt coisa aqui no site em relação a isso.